# Why are blank pages appearing when using the html2pdf library?

Tags: javascript, pdf

Why do I see blank pages when using the html2pdf library for the first time? I'm having trouble understanding why I'm only getting blank pages when I try to download the PDF. I suspect there might be an issue in my code.

I have tried this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Download PDF</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.9.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="downloadPdfButton">Download PDF</button>

  <script>
    function generatePDF() {
      const content = "Hello World";

      const pdfOptions = {
        margin: 10,
        filename: 'downloaded.pdf',
        image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
        html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
        jsPDF: { unit: 'mm', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' }
      };

      html2pdf().from(content).set(pdfOptions).outputPdf().then(function(pdf) {
        const blob = new Blob([pdf], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = 'downloaded.pdf';
        link.click();
      });
    }

    document.getElementById('downloadPdfButton').addEventListener('click', generatePDF);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please inform me if there is an alternative method for downloading an HTML content as a .pdf file.

Comment: Do you have a reason for not using `save()` instead of `outputPdf()` ?

Comment: ah man! you just saved my day, I just written a lot for outputPdf(). save() is working for me perfectly, have to write this only `html2pdf().from(content).set(pdfOptions).save();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing `outputPdf('blod')`

```
html2pdf()
.set(pdfOptions)
.from(content)
.outputPdf('blob')
.then((pdf) => {
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(pdf);
  link.download = 'downloaded.pdf';
  link.click();
});
```

Or just use `save`:

```
html2pdf()
.set(pdfOptions)
.from(content)
.save();
```